# asp.net mvc4 web wizard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web, partial-views, createuserwizard

I want to build a wizard type web form. Practically it is a very long form that I want to break on several sub-pages in a wizard fashion. I would have "back and next" buttons and have to be able to maintain a session or something like it until the form is submitted.

I am considering using partial views which I will flip back and fourth until the form completed, but I am not sure if this would be the or an optimal approach to the solution. I have doubts because partial views are suppose to be reusable across multiple pages through one website rather than on a single page and there might be implications I do not know of.

Please any suggestion would be helpful. 
Let me know if you need more details or clarification.

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you use jquery in your project?

Comment: Yes! I am using it, I was considering to control the partial views with jquery.

Comment: then you can use jquery wizard plugins which will make your life easier.

Comment: Do you have anything particular in mind? Would you post a link? Thank you.

Comment: see my answer i have posted 2 plugins which have demos and lot of options to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try these plugins which will make your life easier.

http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/

http://thecodemine.org/#

http://www.jquery-steps.com/

These are my choices but there are lot of other jquery plugins out there which are made for this specific purposes.

hope this helps.